# How to specialize nested hypotheses in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I've already got the idea of `specialize` in Coq.

It works okay with `specialize (H1 trm_int).`

```
H1 : forall x, value x -> term x.
```

But what about this case

```
H1 : forall x, value x -> forall y, value y -> sub x y.
```

It doesn't work with `specialize (H1 trm_int _trm_int)`.

Edit:

`specialize (H1 trm_int _trm_int)` works fine with

```
H1 : forall x y, value x -> value y -> sub x y.
```

Notice the `forall y` appears in the second premise .

Comment: I'm sorry but what doesn't work?

Comment: @ThéoWinterhalter Hi I updated description, plz check

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your problem.
`specialize` will apply your hypothesis to the arguments you give it. It is not limited to `forall` quantifiers.

Say you have

```
h : nat -> bool
```

you can also use `specialize (h 0)` and you will get

```
h : bool
```

So when you have

```
H1 : forall x, value x -> forall y, value y -> sub x y.
```

and you specialise, you have to use `specialize (H1 some_x some_value_x some_y)`
where `some_x` is an instance for `x`, `some_value_x` is a proof of `value some_x` and `some_y` is an instance for `y`.

Note that there is an alternative using `with` that allows you to specialise using names. Please consider the following example

```
Lemma foo :
  forall (h : forall x, x = 0 -> forall y, y = x -> x = y),
    True.
Proof.
  intro h.
  specialize h with (x := 0) (y := 0).
```

Here you will end up with

```
h: 0 = 0 -> 0 = 0 -> 0 = 0
```

But you could also give the proof directly with

```
specialize (h 0 eq_refl 0).
```